# Regex expression for all positive rational numbers with no leading zeros(not including decimal form)

Tags: regex

I have this expression:

```
([-][1-9]*[/][-][1-9]*|[1-9]*[/][1-9]*|[1-9]+\d*)
```

and my thought process around it was there was three cases.

When the rational number is in the form `a/b`:

```
[1-9]*[/][1-9]*
```

When the rational number is in the form `-a/-b` (turns out to be positive because both numerator and denominator are negative):

```
[-][1-9]*[/][-][1-9]*
```

When the rational number is an integer (because all integers are rational numbers):

```
[1-9]+\d*
```

Is there any way to make this regular expression shorter?

Especially where I have the two cases where its either `a/b` or `-a/-b`, is there any way to combine those two cases into one case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not shorter, but maybe more useful. (Your original expression excludes leading zeroes but also any zero in the expression.)

I came up with:

```
((^|\s+)-?[1-9]\d*\/-?[1-9]\d*($|\s+)|(^|\s+)-?[1-9]\d*($|\s+))
```

This makes use of the special regex characters: `?` (optional), `*` (zero or more), `+` (1 or more), `/d` (numerals), `/s` (whitespace), `^` (line start), `$` (line end), and the construct `(abc|efg)` for alternation.

The `(^|\s+)` and `($|\s+)` isolate the fraction with white space or line marks. The `-?` allows an optional minus sign, `[1-9]` excludes leading zeroes, and the `\d*` allows zero or more trailing digits. The division symbol `\/` is escaped for safety.

If leading zeroes aren't an issue, use

```
((^|\s+)-?\d+\/-?\d+($|\s+)|(^|\s+)-?\d+($|\s+))
```

These versions allow negation in both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex needs some fixing. It doesn't match `-10/-20` but matches invalid numbers like

```
/
-/-
-23/
```

and allows for partial matches which may or may not be desirable. For example, it makes a match on `1/2` for the input `-1/2`, or `123` in `0123`, etc.

You also have a lot of square brackets `[]` that aren't required actually. `[]` are used when you have **multiple** characters to match at **a** specific position, you should use a single `\` to escape special characters, like, `\|`.

> `a/b` or `-a/-b`, is there any way to combine those two cases into one case?

Yes, using a *backreference* `\n` you can match on `b` or `-b` depending on whether a match for `a` or `-a` was found previously *i.e. `-b` becomes invalid if `-a` was not found.*

Try the following regex

```
^((-)?[1-9]\d*\/\2[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*)$
```

`[1-9]\d*` allows numbers to have `0`s anywhere *except* the beginning, `^` and `$` disable partial matches, and `\2` is a *backreference* that captures the presence of the `-` negative sign.

**Matches**

```
1/2
23/56
-1/-2
-10/-20
-34/-12
1234500
```

**Rejects**

```
/
-/-
-23/
01234
-34/12
34/-12
```